# Filepicker.io - image conversions preventing video uploads

Tags: filepicker.io

We're currently working with Filepicker.io to allow users the ability to upload both images and videos. It appears that if we specify image conversions in the Javascript API options, video uploads don't process and instead get stuck at 99.30%. If I remove the 'conversions' option, video uploads process without issue. Is it not possible to specify image conversion options and accept both type of uploads? If so, this should really be specified in the docs.

I attached a JSFiddle with the code in question. http://jsfiddle.net/BYkD4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be an issue on our end, taking a look now. For large files (+1Mb) we split the file into chunks, upload them in parallel, and then reassemble them on the server side. We use browser progress up to the 90% mark, after which we have to "best guess" what the server-side progress looks like, for now at least. That's the reason why it's hanging at 99.30% - it may actually be able to complete if you give it enough time.

In any case, looking into it

Edit: looks like this was an issue on our end. Fix deployed, everything should be working fine. Sorry about the issue

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with re-assembly. As mentioned, if I remove `conversions` from the list of options, the upload completes just fine and the response returns my FPUrl. Do you guys explicitly check if the file is an image before attempting conversions? It seems like it might be failing because it's attempting to perform an image conversion on a video. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The conversion step happens after the reassembly - happy to take a look if you want to chat over email (I'm at brett@filepicker.io)